# jquery .change() in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I'm using the jQuery change to change the values of another select drop down whenever the user changes the month (so that the right number of days is displayed). This works great in all browsers except Firefox :(

Suffice to say the code is a big like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var leap;

$('.dob').change(function() {

var y = $('#ryear option:selected').html(); /* The year selected */
var s = $('#rmonth option:selected').html(); /* The month selected */

});


});
```

Then I alter the data with the variable values in mind.
There are 3 selects with .dob, so its a bit like this

```
<select class="dob" id="rday">
     <option id="01">01</option>
     ....
</select>
<select class="dob" id="rmonth">
     <option id="1876">Jan</option>
     ....
</select>
<select class="dob" id="ryear">
     <option id="1876">1876</option>
     ....
</select>
```

In firefox when I select the month or year select drop down (the value of the day isnt really selected by the script so it isnt affected), well, the drop down flashes and appears, and then instantly disappears on a single click in Firefox.

Any ideas why the script is doing this?

Comment: Those dropdown options - are the "id" attributes really "value" attributes?

Comment: Are there any other events firing that could be interfering? Generally, onchange events don't fire until the field loses focus, so your change function may not be at fault. Do you have any onfocus events, or are you calling .blur() anywhere?

Comment: oh darn, sorry, the IDs arent even numbers, In the real code I'm using name. Haha, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Okay, I've commented all the javascript code so I'm just left with the change() bit and it's still happening! Could it be down to the jQuery rather than me? I'm using firefox 4 beta 12

Comment: Ah ha! It seems it was because the age bit was surrounded by a label tag? Perhaps something was interfering with it. Oh well, thanks for the help anyway guys

Answer (score 1):

ids can not start with numbers.

ids have to be UNIQUE identifiers.

Comment: Is there any w3c page you can link it would be great because I myself have used ids for numbers in many of my projects.

Comment: [html4](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) but not the same with [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: Allowed or not, I wouldn't recommend it. You never know when a browser will behave strangely, so I'd always suggest using safe names (no weird special characters, no starting with numbers, etc.), even if they are technically allowed).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is to do with data type, Instead of `var y = $('#ryear option:selected').html();`

try this 
`var y = $('#ryear option:selected').val();` ||
`var y = $('#ryear option:selected').attr('id');` ||
`parseInt(y);`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend rewriting the code first to be standards compliant, which means replacing IDs with values, i.e. `<option value="1876">`
(BTW IDs, as pointed out, can't start with a digit http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Also, when you're getting the value use `.val()`, so

```
var y = $('#ryear option:selected').val();
```

With those fixes see if you still get the problem.

Also, it occurs to me that if your select handing function "forces" value selection in another select box, which also has the same select handler, there could be interference of some sort. I would recommend, at least for testing purposes, to assign unique id to each select and create unique functions for each.